# PDO es sólo para la conexión con la BD o para todo?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdo

Mi duda es esa. Quisiera saber si PDO se usa únicamente para la conexión con la base de datos o para lo demás también. Si es así, se recomienda usarlo sólo con la BD o con todo? (Mi intención es usarlo en un proyecto de la escuela).

Gracias :)

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "todo"? No somos adivinos. Aquí puedes orientarte sobre qué es PDO: http://php.net/manual/es/intro.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

Si tu duda es si acaso [PDO_MYSQL](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php) reemplaza completamente los casos de uso de MySQLi, la respuesta corta es **SÍ**.

Pero vamos por partes. Si tu primero instalas la el paquete php-mysql por ejemplo con:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Eso habilitará tres extensiones de PHP (en PHP 5.6.x) en donde cada uno contiene su propio driver de conexión y las clases o funciones asociados a éste.

- ext/mysql (obsoleta)
- ext/mysqli
- pdo_mysql

(en PHP7 no existe `ext/mysql` y a cambio habilita la extensión `mysqlnd`).

La extensión `pdo_mysql` es el responsable de proveer el driver para MySQL e implementa la interfaz de [PDO](https://php.net/manual/es/intro.pdo.php). Esta extensión e implementación de PDO reemplazan respectivamente toda la funcionalidad y todos los casos de uso de la extensión `ext/mysqli` y la clase `MySQLi` y con mayor razón todo lo relacionado a la ya obsoleta extensión `ext/mysql`.

Para tu caso de uso, por tanto, la respuesta sigue siendo **SÍ**, puedes hacer un proyecto completo en donde todas las interacciones **con la BBDD** se hagan con PDO, sin la necesidad de usar la clase MySQLi.

Dicho esto, el API de la clase PDO es distinto al API de la clase MySQLi. Aunque hay una relación prácticamente 1:1 con lo que se puede hacer con ambos, la sintaxis de los métodos cambia. Y ese cambio de sintaxis aplica a la configuración de conexión, las sentencias preparadas y su ejecución, y en pocas palabras toda su funcionalidad.

Esto ocurre porque MySQLi está específicamente pensado para MySQL y tiene varios métodos que aplican a funcionalidades propietarias de MySQL. PDO, en cambio, está pensado como una capa de abstracción que te permita interactuar con cualquier motor de base de datos, no sólo con MySQL.